# How to update claims of an authenticated user in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have an identity server that implements OAUTH 2.0/OIDC protocols using the OpenIdDict library in ASP.NET Core. Also, I have an ASP.NET MVC client which uses this IDP for authentication. Also despite storing the passwords of its own users, the IdP acts as a proxy for Google authentication. So in a case, when a user signs up through Google, I want to force him to finish the registration, in order to provide additional information. I do that by redirecting the user to the IdP view with a form. Then the information is sent to the IdP's endpoint which marks the user as registered and redirects him to the client. The problem is that if the user omits completion of registration, he has no access to API and he sees a notification in the App that says that he should finish it and then he gets redirected to the IdP view. The issue is that I use a claim in the API authorization filter to block those requests that come from users that didn't finish registration. I want to update claims when the user finishes registration, so the claim should be updated in the client App too, as well as in the API that the app authenticates to.

**In general, I want to to make the process of registraion completion seamless for users, but I can't find any solution that would help me to accomplish this in Asp.net**

I've tried to do something like that in the IdP endpoint that finished the registration. But that seems to only change the claims on IdP itself, and the effect doesn't propagate. Also, I've tried just calling sign out on signinmanager instance, as well as making a subsequent sign out and sign-in.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
var isUserRegistered = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == AuthConstants.Claims.isUserRegistered );

if (isUserRegistered != null)
{
    await _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user, isUserRegistered );
}

isUserRegistered = new Claim(AuthConstants.Claims.isUserRegistered , true.ToString());
await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, isUserRegistered);
await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
```

**UPD:**
For those, who are struggling with the same issue, take a look a this [article](https://code-maze.com/external-identity-provider-aspnet-core-identity/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage registration in the context of the authorization flow, since you cannot change tokens issued afterwards. Something like this:

- The client redirects to the OpenIddict authorization server
- The AS redirects to the Google identity provider, to authenticate the user
- Before completing the authentication flow, the AS runs a custom registration action if the user is not registered yet, and creates an account
- Finally, return the authorization code to the client, which will then always get the correct claims issued in tokens

Not all authorization servers support this, though it can be important behaviour. An alternative option might be to look into using AS user management APIs from within the app to deal with getting and setting registration data, though that will be a less standard and more complex solution.